# Measure the performance of this year

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am going to measure the performance of this year. The average of the past year records (e.g. 5 years) and this year record will be used to judge how many standard deviation it is and if this year performance has improved or not. However, I have a doubt if the average should also include this year record for calculation?

Answer (score 0):

From a practical standpoint, by including the current year in whatever calculation you want to do, you are probably reducing the chance that the current year's value deviates from whatever baseline expectation you have.